# Reseed identity column to 0 fails - current identity value is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, identity-column

I restore database and delete records in my_table using

```
 delete from my_table;
```

Then I reseed table identity column using this query:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.my_table', reseed, 0);
```

and the message I got is:

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value '0'.

But, when I check current identity using this query:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('my_table', NORESEED);
```

I got this message:

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value 'NULL'.

So, when I'm inserting record in table, first insert gives me an error, but if I try once more then insert succeed.

Why I can't set current identity column value to 0? I need first insert in table to be with identity value 1.

Comment: Did you solved this? I'm having the same issue, but without success to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, use:

```
truncate table my_table;
```

which will reset the identity column automatically.  (Plus, it's going to be faster than deleting the rows using `delete`)

> If the table contains an identity column, the counter for that column
>   is reset to the seed value defined for the column. If no seed was
>   defined, the default value 1 is used. To retain the identity counter,
>   use DELETE instead.

Ref.:  [Truncate Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that I have FKs in table, so truncate table isn't good solution.

Comment: FK's are affected by delete in the same way. Unless of course you have delete cascade turned on, which is very bad practice , IMO.

Comment: unfortunately, i have delete cascade turned on.

Comment: if i reseed to 1 i got the same message (current identity is null, current value is null). but when i insert an record it has identity value 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Is there a way to reset this without truncating though. I have the same issue and cannot truncate because of foreign keys Even though I will be replacing all of the tables and the foreign keys pointing to my table don't exist yet.

Comment: What about this is a table with existing records that we want to keep??

Comment: @xav Exactly, this post is not a real answer to the problem. It's just an alternative to a possible solution. If you've found the solution by now please post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems ridiculous that you can't set/reset an identity column with a single command to cover both cases of whether or not the table has had records inserted. I couldn't understand the behaviour I was experiencing until I stumbled across the question above on SO!

My solution - ugly but works - is to explicitly check the `sys.identity_columns.last_value` table which tells you whether or not the table has had records inserted, and call the appropriate `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command in each case:

```
DECLARE @last_value INT = CONVERT(INT, (SELECT last_value FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'MyTable'));
IF @last_value IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Table newly created and no rows inserted yet; start the IDs off from 1
        DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, 1);
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Table has rows; ensure the IDs continue from the last ID used
        DECLARE @lastValUsed INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM MyTable);
        DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, @lastValUsed);
    END
```